# Angular 16 and Brave Browser issues

Tags: javascript, brave

I started a new Angular project (angular.core 16.1.0) with basically nothing in it just *serve*. In edge I have no issues but in Brave nothing appears and in the console I get

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '='    vendor.js:51165

This is the line in vendor.js

```
              partialText = request.responseType === 'text' ? (partialText ?? '') + (decoder ??= new TextDecoder()).decode(value, {
```

Apparently *??=* doesn't work.
Brave tells me, it's up to date.

Does anyone have an idea what this might cause?

The example code on this site doesn't work either on brave
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_assignment

Comment: I'm using Brave and for me it's working. What version of Brave do you use?

Comment: This one, it sais when "About Brave" all up to date: Version 1.11.60 Chromium: 83.0.4103.97 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: Your Brave is heavily outdated. This feature was added with Chrome 85, so no wonder it's not working for you. We are already on Chrome 115. Something must be wrong with your Brave updater. Try re-installing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So apparently the update-functionallity doesn't really work on brave, even though it sais "up to date" it really wasn't at all. Just reinstall brave and it works.